# Default the view to 'Tile View' in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am working on SSRS 2008 and was wondering that if there is a way to change the view of the report list to "Tile View" instead of the default "Details View".

Here's a screenshot of the Web Portal Report Manager

[image: screenshot of SSRS Report Manager]

Here the reports are being displayed what called as the "Tile View" (top-right).

What if I need to open reports-list in Tile View by default instead of Details View (which just display reports just like Thumbnails in Windows Explorer)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Linked screenshot is actually showing "Details view" (top right button labeled "Tile view" is in fact button that you need to click to change view to "Tile view")

So if I understood what you really want correctly this should be solution:

Bookmark this link http://localhost/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx?ViewMode=Detail in IE and it will get you to root Reports folder in "Details view".

Comment: Link only works if you have Reporting Services server installed on your local machine, if that is not the case then navigate to your Reports folder as usual, click "Details view" (top right) and then bookmark that page..